# Errors compiling OpenCL ICD loader on linux

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, cmake, opencl

Trying to compile the test OpenCL ICD driver: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-icd-1.2.11.0.tgz on Linux (ubuntu 12.04).

Building as per README:

```
wget http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-icd-1.2.11.0.tgz
tar xvf opencl-icd-1.2.11.0.tgz
cd icd/inc
mkdir CL
cd CL
cp /usr/include/CL/* .
cd ../..
make
```

But make throws errors such as:

```
In file included from icd.c:42:0:
icd_dispatch.h:105:5: error: unknown type name 'cl_device_partition_property'
icd_dispatch.h:111:30: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CL_API_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_2'
icd_dispatch.h:114:30: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CL_API_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_2'
icd_dispatch.h:177:5: error: unknown type name 'cl_image_desc'
...
```

Looks like cl_device_partition_property should be referencing the opencl header ~/icd/inc/CL/cl_ext.h, but isn't picking it up for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: why is it flagged cmake?

Comment: @Peter the build process uses a combination of make and cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using OpenCL 1.1 headers, whereas the ICD you are building is for 1.2. The `cl_device_partition_property` and `cl_image_desc` types are defined in `cl.h`, but were only added in OpenCL 1.2.

You can download the OpenCL 1.2 header from the [Khronos OpenCL Registry](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).